# SaveFileDialog blocking removeable drive

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm using a SaveFileDialog to let a user pick a directory and filename on a removeable drive.
Afterwards I create that file, write to it, and close it again.

By then the file itself is not locked (editable, deleteable), but I can't eject the drive because windows claims it is still in use. I have to exit the application before an eject is possible.

Incidentally the drive gets locked even when I only pick the file with the SaveFileDialog. Hitting "Cancel" on the dialog doesn't cause the problem

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = ".csv";
dlg.InitialDirectory = mySettings.defaultPath;
dlg.Filter = "(CSV-Dateien) *.csv|";
dlg.FileName = exportDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".csv";

if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK){
    // USB-Drive is ejectable
}else{
    // USB-Drive is locked
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found 2 **Solutions**:

The Dialog changes the current working directory once the user clicks "save". It's not the file that was blocking the removable drive, but the program itself .

So you either need to readjust the working directory once you're done:

```
String oldDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
// ... do dialog...
Environment.CurrentDirectory = oldDir;
```

or you simply configure the file dialog to restore the directory before calling ShowDialog()

```
dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
dlg.ShowDialog()
```