# Saving to Removable Drive in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, save

In my SL3 application I prompt the user to choose a save location, which will most likely be a removable drive due to the target audience.

If the user attempts to eject/remove the drive then Windows complains that it is "in use".

If the user then saves the file again but this time to a fixed drive then the removable drive can then be ejected/removed.

It is almost as if [this .NET issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451340/savefiledialog-blocking-removeable-drive) is happening. Sadly, because of the reduced .NET support and SL security restrictions both of the workarounds cannot be used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SaveFileDialog? if not - then that is not the case.

Without seeing any code it's kind of hard to answer, but is it possible you are not closing the file (File.Close())?

As far as i recall you CANNOT change the current directory in SL , so i kind of doubt the cause of your problem is the same as the solution in your link.

Comment: I am using SaveFileDialog. Then: filestream.flush(); filestream.close(); filestream.Dispose(); filestream=null;

Comment: Although it is not possible for user-code to change the current directory, I think it is possible for internal .NET code to do it, as fundamentally a SL application is just an executable running on the user's PC.

Comment: Silverlight is a special executable because it lives in a sandbox that prevents it from doing certain things, however - it's possible that the underlying win32 form has access to change the current directory. Can you verify that the current directory really changed? Can you open the dialog at a pre-defined location? I.e "my documents"?

Comment: You can't tell the dialog to open at a specific folder, but it remembers the last folder used, so this is stored "somewhere" out of the application developer's reach. I think it is this remembering that is causing the drive to be marked as "in use".